# Large Items Sync Document Libraries between On Prem Site and SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library

With no access to OneDrive, is there a way to sync (prefer automatically) Document Library 1 (with large items and subfolders) from SharePoint Site 1 to Document Library 2 in SharePoint Site 2?

Users can only access SharePoint Site 2, NOT SharePoint Site 1; I am able to access Site 1 as  SPO administrator, Site 2 as SP on prem site owner.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it is not possible to sync document library from SharePoint on-premise to SharePoint online automatically.

Maybe you could try to use SharePoint Migration Tool to migrate libraries from on-premises SharePoint sites to SharePoint online sites as a workaround.

For Reference: [Overview of the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Comment: Is Power Automate a solution?